# Rails, triggering custom action on link

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, render

I'm trying to render an edit form when someone clicks on an object in a list.

I made a test action in my **controller** like this:

```
def test    
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

In my **view** I made a link like this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('icons/edit3.png'),
        :remote => true,
        :controller => :aliens, 
        :id => alien.expansion.id,
        :ph_id => alien.id,
        :action => :test 
%>
```

and in my test.js.erb

```
console.log('testing');
```

I also made a custom **route**

```
  get 'expansions/:id/aliens/:ph_id/test' => 'aliens#test', as: :test
```

This works great. Everytime I click on an object it prints out in the console.

The problem is that I want the .js.erb to render the form. BUT, if I add this code to the js:

```
$('.dialog__content').append('<%= j render :partial => 'editform', :formats => :html %>');
```

or

```
$('.dialog__content').html("<%= j render(@editform) %>'");
```

or

```
$('.dialog__content').html("<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'editform') %>");
```

It returns GET "My path" 404 (Not Found)

And If I add variables to my action like this:

```
def test
    @aliens = Alien.all
    @expansions = Expansion.all
    @expansion = Expansion.find(params[:expansion_id])
    @alien = @aliens.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end

end
```

It also returns:  GET "My path" 404 (Not Found)

What should I do? 
Thanks.

**Update:** 
My editform partial, 
Seems like the variables is the problem. I tried rendering a partial with only html in it, and that works fine.

```
<div class="hidden_form form_holder">
    <%=form_for [@expansion, @alien], :remote => true, :html => {:class => "add edit",  :multipart => true }  do |f| %>
        <h2>Rediger Alien </h2>
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>

        <%= f.label :difficulty %>
        <%= f.select :difficulty, ['Beginner', 'Intermediate', 'Hard']%>

        <%= f.label :tokens %>
        <%= f.number_field :tokens %>

        <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="byside">
                <%= f.check_box :gamesetup %>
                <%= f.label :gamesetup, :class => 'check'%>
            </div>
            <div class="byside">
                <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
        </div>

        </div>


        <%= f.submit %>

     <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the `editform` partial contain? What resource is the 404 saying isn't found?

Comment: It has the form in it. I updated my post now, and added it to the bottom.

Comment: Do you have access to the logs? Maybe this way we could find the exact line where it is giving an error